# ObservableCollection showing up in UI, but slow in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

There is a page where the user selects parameters to show the proper collection then on button click jumps to the next page (Coll) where it should show up.

**User Selection Page XAML:**

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext><xyz:UserSelectionViewModel</ContentPage.BindingContext>
...
<Button x:Name="Start" Command="{Binding LoadData}" Pressed="StartClick"/>
```

**User Selection Page C#:**

```
private async void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var vm = (CollViewModel)BindingContext;

   vm.Hard = HardButtonSelected == Hard;
   ...
   vm.Subject = vm.Subject.ToLower();
}
```

**UserSelectionViewModel:**

```
public class UserSelectionViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
   public UserSelectionViewModel()
   {
            _dataStore = DependencyService.Get<IDataStore>();
            _pageService = DependencyService.Get<IPageService>();

            LoadData= new AsyncAwaitBestPractices.MVVM.AsyncCommand(FilterData);

            FilteredData = new ObservableRangeCollection<Items>();
   }
   public async Task FilterData()
   {
            FilteredData.Clear();
            var filtereddata = await _dataStore.SearchData(Hard, Subject).ConfigureAwait(false);
            FilteredData.AddRange(filtereddata);
            OnPropertyChanged("FilteredData");

            Debug.WriteLine(FilteredData.Count());
            await Device.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(() => _pageService.PushAsync(new Coll(FilteredData)));
   }  
}
```

**Coll XAML:**

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext><xyz:CollViewModel</ContentPage.BindingContext>
...
<CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type z:Coll}}, Path=InheritedData}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CollTemplateSelector}">
...
```

**Coll C#:**

```
public partial class Coll : ContentPage
{
     public ObservableRangeCollection<Feladatok> InheritedData { get; set; }

     public Coll(ObservableRangeCollection<Feladatok> x)
     {
            InitializeComponent();

            InheritedData = x;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(InheritedData));
     }
}
```

**CollViewModel:**

```
public class CollViewModel : UserSelectionViewModel { ... }
```

**BaseViewModel:**

```
private ObservableRangeCollection<Feladatok> inheriteddata;

public ObservableRangeCollection<Feladatok> InheritedData
{
      get
      {
          return inheriteddata;
      }
      set
      {
          if (value != inheriteddata)
          {
              inheriteddata = value;
              PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("InheritedData"));
          }
      }
}
```

Managed to make it work like this with the help of Jason's tips. My only concern remaining is that: Won't this slow down the page that I load the observable collection two times basically? Is it a good practice as I have made it?

Comment: you are not passing any data between the two pages.  A page does not inherit the prior pages `BindingContext`.  If you want to pass some value when navigating to the page, pass it as a parameter to the constructor.

Comment: If two pages have the same BindingContext defined in the XAML that means they will each have their **own instance** of that class, they will not share an instance

Comment: Try Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("FilteredData")));

See if that gets you anywhere.

Comment: also, if you use nameof(FilteredData) instead of "FilteredData" it makes refactoring and keeping track of references cleaner.

Comment: @Jason Okay, what I did is created a new UserSelectionViewModel then inherited like so - `CollViewModel : UserSelectionViewModel` and passed the FilteredData colletion from UserSelectionViewModel to Coll Page and initiliazed it as filteredInherited. Binded to this as `{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type z:CollPage}, Path=filteredInherited}`. But the problem is the same. Any idea?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the updated code

Comment: You should also not need that complex of a binding expression

Comment: You said that `There is a page where the user selects parameters to show the proper collection then on button click jumps to the next page (Coll) where it should show up`. So, you just want to show the data, but the data will not change? It seems that you can achieve what you want without ViewModel.

Comment: @Jason Thanks for the tips, I have updated my code and question.

Comment: @JianweiSun-MSFT I need to modify some things after that later on, so I need the view model.

Comment: @NathanM Changed it to 'nameof()' thanks for the tip.

Comment: if the constructor of `Coll` you are assigning `InheritedData = x;` - where `InheritedData` is a property of the page, **not** the VM.  You need to assign the value to the VM, since that is your `BindingContext`

Comment: @Jason How do I do that, if its coming from the `Coll` constructor not the VM?

Comment: cast the BindingContext to the VM and assign it.  That may or not be possible in the constructor, you might have to do it in OnAppearing

Answer (score 0):

Eventually set the BindingContext to the VM and Binding from there. I still feel like it could be done more efficently or maybe that's how it is done. ViewModels are still new for me and I feel like it's much more code and slower with it. But I will close this, as it is working now.